# With a HashMap<T, HashMap<T, i32>>, how can I insert the inner HashMap by the outer key?

Tags: rust, hashmap

For example, if I have a vector `[1, 2]`, and I want to build a HashMap like `<1: <2: 0>>`, how can I insert the key and value? (The 0 is a default number), you can use x[0], x[1] to describe the elements in the vector.
I try to use `map.insert(k,v)`, however, I don't know how to write the second parameter.

Comment: Might be a good idea to look at the [HashMap docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) and see what you can do with it. `map.entry(k).or_default().insert(v, 0)` might be what you want.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to, given a vector `[n, m]`, insert a (key, value) pair into a HashMap where the key is `n` and the value is *another* HashMap, containing the (key, value) pair, `(m, 0)`. That is, in JSON:

```json
{ n: { m: 0 } }
```

As one commenter mentioned, you'll need to create the second map.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

// I have arbitrarily picked `u8` for `T` here.
let mut map: HashMap<u8, HashMap<u8, i32>> = HashMap::new();

// And here's the vector we're given, maybe as a function argument:

let v: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2];

// So we start by constructing our sub-map:
let mut sub_map: HashMap<u8, i32> = HashMap::new();
sub_map.insert(v[1], 0);

// And then we insert it into our outer map:
map.insert(v[0], sub_map);
```

So this solution answers your question, but it's kind of a crummy one, because I can easily imagine that you will want to process any number of 2-vectors and generate a more complicated map; for example, perhaps you want to, given this set of inputs:

```
[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 5], [3, 5]
```

arrive at this map:

```json
{
  1: { 2: 0, 3: 0 },
  2: { 5: 0 },
  3: { 5: 0 }
}
```

The above technique would have blown the `{ 2: 0 }` out of the first inner value when inserting the `{ 3: 0 }`. What we probably want instead is a kind of "update or insert" (I have heard database guys use the term "upsert").

So we want something like this:

```rust
map.entry(v[0]).or_default().insert(v[1], 0);
```

The `.or_default()` will insert an empty inner HashMap (the type returned by `HashMap::default()`) keyed to the value of `v[0]` if the outer HashMap doesn't yet have one (then the `.insert(v[1], 0)` inserts the values you want in the inner map).

So in action it might look something like this:

```rust
let v: Vec<Vec<u8>> = vec![
    vec![1, 2],
    vec![1, 3],
    vec![2, 5],
    vec![3, 5],
];

let mut map: HashMap<u8, HashMap<u8, i32>> = HashMap::new();

for u in v.iter() {
    map.entry(u[0]).or_default().insert(u[1], 0);
}

println!("{:#?}", &map);
/* should produce something like
{
    1: {
        2: 0,
        3: 0,
    },
    2: {
        5: 0,
    },
    3: {
        5: 0,
    },
}
*/
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman Or nicer, `or_default()`.

Comment: One man's nit is another man's forehead slapper. Thanks, @JohnKugelman, @ChayimFriedman; I always forget about the `Default` trait.